# Oozie job fails with E0729 error

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, oozie

I tried running the sample code from https://github.com/oozie-book/examples/tree/master/chapter-01/identity-wf (Identity MapReduce job), but my job gets killed. Here is the job info

```
[root@slave4 hdfs]# oozie job -oozie http://localhost:11000/oozie -info 0000000-160616112709683-oozie-oozi-W
Job ID : 0000000-160616112709683-oozie-oozi-W
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Workflow Name : identity-WF
App Path      : hdfs://slave4.hdp.com:8020/user/root/testing/app
Status        : KILLED
Run           : 0
User          : root
Group         : -
Created       : 2016-06-16 02:30 GMT
Started       : 2016-06-16 02:30 GMT
Last Modified : 2016-06-16 02:41 GMT
Ended         : 2016-06-16 02:41 GMT
CoordAction ID: -

Actions
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ID                                                                                Status    Ext ID                 Ext Status Err Code
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0000000-160616112709683-oozie-oozi-W@:start:                                  OK        -                      OK         -
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0000000-160616112709683-oozie-oozi-W@identity-MR                              ERROR     job_1464854703747_0089 FAILED/KILLED-
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0000000-160616112709683-oozie-oozi-W@fail                                     OK        -                      OK         E0729
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

A simple logging workflow based on a jar file I wrote also fails with the same error. In the application overview on the Hadoop UI, this is what I see

```
User:   root
Name:   oozie:launcher:T=map-reduce:W=identity-WF:A=identity-MR:ID=0000000-160616112709683-oozie-oozi-W
Application Type:   MAPREDUCE
Application Tags:   
YarnApplicationState:   FAILED
Queue:  default
FinalStatus Reported by AM:     FAILED
Started:    Thu Jun 16 11:30:52 +0900 2016
Elapsed:    3sec
Tracking URL:   History
Log Aggregation Status  SUCCEEDED
Diagnostics:    
Application application_1464854703747_0089 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1464854703747_0089_000002 exited with exitCode: -1000
For more detailed output, check application tracking page:http://slave4.hdp.com:8088/cluster/app/application_1464854703747_0089Then, click on links to logs of each attempt.
Diagnostics: ExitCodeException exitCode=2: gzip: /hadoop/yarn/local/filecache/36_tmp/tmp_mapreduce.tar.gz is a directory -- ignored
tar: This does not look like a tar archive
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
Failing this attempt. Failing the application.
```

I am not sure how to resolve this issue, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It says: For more detailed output, check application tracking page: http://slave4.hdp.com:8088/cluster/app/application_1464854703747_0089 - please, provide some info from that page.

Comment: This is the same application overview from the Hadoop UI I included.

Comment: You need to click on the `History`, from `Tracking URL:   History`. Then go to logs of the launched maps. There you need to check the `stderr` and `stdout` for more details.

Comment: In yarn logs of job_1464854703747_0089 you will get another yarn application id may be immediate next one job_1464854703747_0090 which is actual yarn application which represent map-reduce job. you will get error logs in there application.